# Get form from rendered controller

Tags: forms, symfony, controller, twig, render

I have such problem with symfony2.

I have base.html.twig and this base is the template for others twigs.
I want to render controller, which contains form with locale-type input field.
The form will be used to change language of site.

My LanguageController:

```
<?php

namespace Soczewki\PlatformaBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;


class LanguageController extends Controller {

  public function createAction(Request $Request)
    {

      $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->setAction(null)
            ->add('locale', 'locale', array(
                'label'     => ' ',
                'choices'   => array('pl' => 'Polski', 'de' => 'Deutsch', 'en' => 'English'),
                'data' => $this->getRequest()->getLocale(),
                'required'  => true))
              ->add('submit', 'submit')
              ->getForm();

     $form->handleRequest($Request); 

     if($form->isValid()) {
         $this->getRequest()->setLocale('en');
     }

     return $this->render("SoczewkiPlatformaBundle::myForm.html.twig",
            array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
                'req' => $r
            ));
    }


}
```

The whole base.html.twig:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block pageTitle %}{% endblock %}</title>
        {#js#}
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/soczewkiplatforma/js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/soczewkiplatforma/js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
        {#/js#}   
        {% block stylesheets %}
            <link href="{{ asset('bundles/soczewkiplatforma/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="{{ asset('bundles/soczewkiplatforma/css/my-style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        {% endblock stylesheets %}         

    </head>
    <body>



    {% if app.security.getToken().getUser().getAuthKey() is defined %}    
        {% if app.security.getToken().getUser().getAuthKey() is not empty %}
            {% set diff =  ( app.security.getToken().getUser().getEndDate()|date('U') - "now"|date('U') ) / 3600  %}
            <div style="width: 300px; height: 140px; position: absolute; bottom: 90px; right: 50px;" class="alert alert-danger alert-error">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <strong>Uwaga!</strong> Twoje konto nadal nie zostało aktywowane!<br />
            Pozostało Ci: <span class="badge">{{ diff[0:2] }} godzin {{   ( diff[3:] * 60 )[0:2]   }} minut </span> 
            <br /><br />
            <a href="{{ url('soczewki_platofrma_account') }}#activate_form_auth_key"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Wpisz kod</button></a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="alert">Zamknij</button>
            </div>
        {% endif %}

        {% set hasParams = app.request.get('id') %}

        {% if hasParams is empty %}
            {% set currentPath = url( app.request.attributes.get( '_route', app.request.attributes.get('_route_params'))) %}
        {% else %}
            {% set currentPath = url( app.request.attributes.get( '_route', app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')),{'id': 0}   ) %}
        {% endif %}

        {% set dirs = currentPath|split('/') %}
        {% set flag = "" %}
        {% set url = "" %}

        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="{{ url('soczewki_platofrma_test') }}">Główna</a></li>  

            {% for key, dir in dirs %} 

                {% if url is not empty %}
                    {% set url = url ~ '/' ~ dir %}
                {% else %}
                    {% set url = url ~ dir %}
                {% endif %}
                {% if flag == true %}

                    {% if '=' in dir %}   
                        {% set _temp = dir|split('=') %}
                    {% else %}
                        {% set _temp = dir|split(' ') %}
                    {% endif %}

                    {% if key + 1 == dirs|length %}
                        <li class="active"> {{ _temp[0]|capitalize|replace('-',' ') }} </li> 
                    {% else %}
                        <li><a href="{{ url }}"> {{ _temp[0]|capitalize|replace('-',' ') }} </a></li> 
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}  
                {% if dir == 'app_dev.php' %}
                    {% set flag = true %}
                {% endif %}  
            {% endfor %}

            <li class="dropdown" style="float: right !important;">    
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Zalogowano jako: {{ app.security.getToken().getUser().getName() }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="{{ path('soczewki_platofrma_account') }}">Moje konteło</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="{{ path('logout') }}">Wyloguj</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </li>
        </ol>

    {% else %}           
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="{{ url('soczewki_platofrma_test') }}">Główna</a></li>   
            <!--- logowanie --->
            <li class="dropdown" style="float: right !important;">    
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Zaloguj <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px; left: -200px;">


                    <form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
                    <label for="username">Email/NIP:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" />
                    <br />

                    <label for="password">Hasełko:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />
                    <br /><br />

                    <button type="submit">Loguj do Afganistanu</button>
                    </form>

                </div>   
            </li>
            <!--- log ---->
        </ol>         
    {% endif %}  

     {{ render(controller('SoczewkiPlatformaBundle:Language:create')) }}

    {% block pageContainer %}

    {% endblock %}  

    </body>
</html>
```

Nothing shows and I get too any error.
Why is it like that?

// codes updated

myForm.html.twig:

```
{{ dump(req) }}

{{ form(form) }}
```

and LocaleListener.php:

```
<?php
namespace Soczewki\PlatformaBundle\Translations;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class LocaleListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct($defaultLocale = 'pl')
    {
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
            return;
        }

        // try to see if the locale has been set as a _locale routing parameter
        if ($locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale')) {
            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        } else {
            // if no explicit locale has been set on this request, use one from the session
            $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // must be registered before the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 17)),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post "SoczewkiPlatformaBundle::base.html.twig"?
Why do you check isset($form)?

Comment: Can you post the code of the file base.html.twig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a situation where you are calling the same method an infinite amount of times until the page just dies.

You original base is being rendered which is in the end rendering the `SoczewkiPlatformaBundle::base.html.twig` template. Within this template a `render()` is calling an action that is then rendering the `SoczewkiPlatformaBundle::base.html.twig` template, which then calls the `render()`, which then render `SoczewkiPlatformaBundle::base.html.twig`, and on and on...

You need to specify a template for the form to be rendered in rather than the base and then call that in your `changeAction`.

For example...

`Soczewki\PlatformaBundle\Controller\LanguageController`

```
public function changeAction(Request $Request)
{
    // ..

    return $this->render("SoczewkiPlatformaBundle:Locale:change_form.html.twig",
        array(
            'form' => isset($form) ? $form->createView() : null,
        ));
}
```

`SoczewkiPlatformaBundle:Locale:change_form.html.twig`

```
{{ form_start(form, {'method': 'POST', 'action': 'your_locale_change_route' }) }}
    {{ form_row(form.locale) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Your next problem would be that your `changeAction` isn't actually performing an action (apart from creating a form), although you may just be wanting that page to show before you get to that part.

Comment: Ok, I passed form to new twig, then tried to embed did like that:                      `{% embed "SoczewkiPlatformaBundle::myForm.html.twig" %}
{% endembed %}` and then display in new twig, but now I'm getting: Variable "form" does not exist in SoczewkiPlatformaBundle::myForm.html.twig at line 1

Comment: Who said to use embed? You the same `render(controller())`, just change the template that is rendered.

Comment: But now I have problem with changing the locale... Code updated.

Comment: I'd ask it all in a separate question to be honest. What is `'req' => $r`? Is the the request or something? You can get the request in your template using `app.request`. Your

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this code where you want that the form appear

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

---

Edited after the comments below;

Create a file named myForm.html.twig and put in SoczewkiPlatformaBundle;
Now write this code inside:

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

now your controller should be:

```
public function changeAction(Request $Request)
    {


      $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('locale', 'locale', array(
                'label'     => 'user.locale',
                'required'  => true,
                'choices'   => array('en' => 'English', 'de' => 'Deutsch', 'pl' => 'Polish')
                                ))
                    ->getForm();

     $form->handleRequest($Request); 


     return $this->render("SoczewkiPlatformaBundle::myForm.html.twig",
            array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            ));


    }
```

Comment: There is: [2014-07-14 17:47:15] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". [] []

Comment: see the edited answer. Does your logs contain nothing beyond that line?

Comment: that's not the answer for my question... I can pass form to view, but I want to render controller with form to base view, coz I have much views. And the form is destianted for changing language

Comment: You made a conceptual error; you call {{ render(controller('SoczewkiPlatformaBundle:Language:change')) }} inside a base, but this controller render the base too. This cause an infinite loop! That's why I posted this solution

Comment: Did you try my solution?